# Add Item to DynamoDB Table and Propagate Change to AWS Amplify

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have an AWS Amplify project that is using DataStore and I'm trying to add multiple items to a table. I've tried using DynamoDB and the put_item() method to add the items like this:

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
response = client.put_item(
    Item={
        'AlbumTitle': {
            'S': 'Somewhat Famous',
        },
        'Artist': {
            'S': 'No One You Know',
        },
        'SongTitle': {
            'S': 'Call Me Today',
        },
    },
    ReturnConsumedCapacity='TOTAL',
    TableName='Music',
)
```

I'm able to successfully add items to my table in DynamoDB; however, the added items don't show up when looking at the table's items through Admin UI. Any tips?